# show the selected value in dropdown on edit jsp page on page load (Spring MVC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to show the selected value in the dropdown on page load.
My edit page shows a value, country. Now user belongs to USA, so USA should be selected by default on page load. I can use javascript or jquery.

I found few help on internet but they were with scriplets (<%   %>) and I don't want to use them.

I am passing a List which has Id and Value. Also I have Id in another object.
I can write the code by introducing a for loop in jsp and showing the value, but may be I am doing some mistake there. Also wanted to know if there is any better way to do this.

I am using Spring MVC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Now user belongs to USA, so USA should be selected by default on page load.". You know before hand user belongs to some country.

Assuming you have a pojo Country as:

```
    public class Country{ 
        String countryName;
        String countryId;
        //setters and getters
    }

    public class YourForm{
        List<Country> countryList;
        String selectedCountryId;
        ...
        //setters and getters
    }
```

In your controller method which delegates to the jsp:

```
    ...
    YourForm form = new YourForm();
    //set your countrylist to form 
    //set  country user belongs to - selectedCountryId - since you know before hand user belongs to some country.
    model.addAttribute("yourForm", form):
    ...
```

Now access it in jsp as:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form:form id="yourForm" modelAttribute="yourForm" method="post">

    <tr>
        <td width="50%" class="label">
            <form:select id="countryId" path="selectedCountryId" title='Select Country'>
                <option value="">Please Select</option>
                <form:options items="${countryList}" itemValue="countryId" itemLabel="countryName"/>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </body>
```

Since selectedCountryId is already set in controller you will see that country as auto selected in the jsp.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly fine. I was using <select tag.....replaced it with <form:select and it worked ok.